# Call constant property on class like static?

Tags: c#, inheritance, static-members

I got an abstract base class

```
public class Base
{
  public abstract String Info { get; }
}
```

and some children.

```
public class A : Base
{
  public override String Info { get { return "A does ..."; } }
}

public class B : Base
{
  public override String Info { get { return "B does ..."; } }
}
```

This is mere a constant but I want to make sure using `Base` that all classes implement it.

Now I sometimes do not have an object instance but want to access `A.Info` - this is not possible due it is a instance property.

Is there another way than implementing the same property on instance AND on static level? That would be feel like a duplicate violating DRY programming style.

---

**NEW EDIT**: I now see this two solutions:

```
public class Base
{
  public abstract String ClassInfo { get; }
}

public class A : Base
{
  public override String ClassInfo { get { return Info; } }

  public static String Info { get { return "A does ..."; } }
}

public class B : Base
{
  public override String ClassInfo { get { return Info; } }

  public static String Info { get { return "In B we do ..."; } }
}
```

With this I can do with any `object` of type `Base` something like `object.ClassInfo` but also use the value in my factory hardcoded like `if(A.Info) return new A()`. But I have to implement two properties for the same information in every class.

On the other hand:

```
public class Base
{
  public abstract String ClassInfo { get; }

  public static String GetClassInfo<T>() where T : BaseControl, new()
  {
    T obj = new T();
    return obj.ClassInfo;
  }
}

public class A : Base
{
  public override String ClassInfo { get { return "text A"; } }
}

public class B : Base
{
  public override String ClassInfo { get { return "text B"; } }    
}
```

Due to the abstract `Base` it is made sure that `ClassInfo` is always implemented. Calls with `obj.ClassInfo` and `Base.GetClassInfo<A>()` are okay. But with this every child of `Base` must have a default constructor without arguments and we loose performance with the unneccessary created instance.

Is there any other idea? Which one would you prefer and why?

Comment: er... `public static abstract` and `public static override` .....? that won't compile... and neither will the classes without the keyword `class`. I don't think we can provide a sensible answer until the question is clarified

Comment: What do you have against implementing an instance property?

Comment: public static override? I have a feeling that shouldn't compile..

Comment: You are right, up to now I did not get to the compile step. I will edit the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need specific return results of your static properties, you're better of either

a) Instance properties
2) Attributes

In the example you've already given, you've got an instance of `Base`, which means you can just make the instance property virtual:

```
public class Base
{
    public virtual string Info { get { return "From Base"; } }
}

public class A : Base
{
    public override string Info { get { return "From A"; } }
}
```

If you wanted to go the attribute route, you define it as such:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = true)]
public class InfoAttribute : Attribute
{
    public InfoAttribute(string info) { this.Info = info; }

    public string Info { get; private set; }
}

[InfoAttribute(Info = "From Base")]
public class Base
{
    public string GetInfo()
    {
        var attr = GetType()
            .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(InfoAttribute), true)
            .FirstOrDefault();

        return (attr == null) ? null : attr.Info;
    }
}

[InfoAttribute(Info = "From A")]
public class A : Base { }
```

If you wanted to call it as a static function call, you could make this change:

```
public static string GetInfo(Base instance)
{
    var attr = instance.GetType()
        .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(InfoAttribute), true)
        .FirstOrDefault();

    return (attr == null) ? null : attr.Info;
}
```

And then call it as: `Base.GetInfo(instance);`.  All in all, not very elegant!

Comment: That's interesting. Can the info be called like `objectA.GetInfo()` and like `A.GetInfo()`?

Comment: It's an instance method, the other way you could do it, is make it a static function, and pass in the `Base` instance. I'll update the example.

Comment: The problem is the static call should be possible without instance by writing `A.GetInfo()`. I will try to have a static property with the real constant value and in `Base` a instance property which calls the static property through reflection.

Comment: I was not happy with your static GetInfo because of the instance. But my 2nd solution posted in the question solves this issue with a generic type parameter. So now I will combine the attribute approach with an instance GetInfo() and a static GetInfo<T>(). Will mark your answer as the solution if it works.

Comment: It works for me. I did the static `GetInfo` as a generic method to give it the type and no instance. I did an instance `GetInfo` in parallel. Compiles and unit test is satisfied, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible.
`static` members cannot be virtual or abstract.

You should make an abstract instance property.

Comment: An instance property works but I need the same information on instance and class level. What is best practice? Is doubling it the only solution?

Answer (score 0):

Statics can't be overridden.  If you truly want to do something like that, you'd want an instance property that is virtual in the base that gets overridden in the subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

Does it compiled? I don't think so. Static cannot be marked as override, virtual or abstract.

Comment: This is not a very helpful answer.

Comment: So... you copied a piece of SLaks's answer... I'm afraid that doesn't make it much more useful. Try to contribute a new idea to the discussion.

Comment: I just cannot believe that you reviewed my answer so fast. Thanks.